# Windows 8 sensors. Testing on emulator

Tags: emulation, windows-8, sensors

I don't have a Windows 8 tablet. 
On tablet emulator and on desktop Windows 8 the following code returns `null`:

```
lightSensor = Windows.Devices.Sensors.LightSensor.getDefault();
```

Same for other sensors (but not for geolocation).

Can i somehow test my code without device ?
I don't care about any sensible data returned, but it would be great to test code correctness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buy a light sensor :P

Tbh ways of test this king of things at the moment are limited.
IMO if you want tablet with Windows 8 you should hack one of the tablets on the martket and install Windows 8 on it. Microsoft installed Win8 on few Samsungs to present Office 2013 so it can`t be that hard :)

But this is a bit off top. Back to the question. IMO you can`t test it with out some device with light sensor. I found many examples of your code but none of them where tested.